# Subset data frame by string

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Suppose I have a data frame with 7 variables.  I want to subset the data frame based on the contents of one column automatically.  The column is Department and there are 17 different values.  I would like R to look at the column "Dept" and create a new data frame for each Dept containing all other rows.  This would be the equivalent of "Split Worksheet" in Minitab.  For now, I have to run the subset command 17 times to create a data frame for each. Can R do this automatically based on the column content?

Best and thanks!

Comment: Got a sample?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: yes that will do the trick, but it outputs into the console instead of placing data for each department in its own data frame (preferably named by department)

Comment: it makes a list of `data.frames` which you can assign just like you would.  R almost never changes data out from under you, instead it manipulates it and returns it.  The default return is stdout but you can use `<-` or `=` to assign to a new variable.

Comment: @BobWainscott: it's usually better to leave them in a list, especially if you're going to perform similar analyses on each data.frame.  Otherwise you will likely find yourself right back in a situation where you need to run another command 17 times...

Comment: Thank you a ton, the data is now split.  I am bit sketchy on analyzing it without seeing it in front of me as a data frame.  I am using RStudio.  Great website!  Cheers.  Actually I can feed them into a data frame by dep1 = out$dep1

Answer (score 5):

```
out<-split(df,df$Dept)

out[[1]]
```

# etc to access dataframes

or

```
out$Dept1
```

to give a concrete example

```
df<-data.frame(Dept=c('a','a','b','b','c','d','d'),acs=c(111,112,222,223,333,444,445))
out<-split(df,df$Dept)
out
> out
$a
  Dept acs
1    a 111
2    a 112

$b
  Dept acs
3    b 222
4    b 223

$c
  Dept acs
5    c 333

$d
  Dept acs
6    d 444
7    d 445

dept.names<-names(out)

> dept.names[1]
[1] "a"

> out[[dept.names[1]]] # dataframe for department 1
  Dept acs
1    a 111
2    a 112

> out[[dept.names[2]]] # dataframe for department 2
  Dept acs
3    b 222
4    b 223


> is.data.frame(out[[dept.names[2]]])
[1] TRUE
```